# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a laplacian vs gaussian pyramid

Tags: image, image-processing

I can find plenty of resources on how laplacian and gaussian image pyramids are constructed but I can't find any information on what are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other.

Comment: depends on the use case. you are asking for a blanket decision, which is impossible. compressibility can certainly be a concern... but only for storage, not for algorithms.

Comment: @ZacharyWhitley You can see **Lesson 3** in this [Course](http://crowley-coutaz.fr/jlc/Courses/2020/GVR.VO/GVR-VO.html), it explains in detail what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Laplacian pyramid is saving only the difference of images, it consists of sparse matrix (lots of zeroes) which can be saved much more efficiently. It is also used for image compression ([Link](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/pyramid83.pdf))

Low memory requirement is the main advantage of Laplacian pyramid.

Comment: I would contest the "low memory requirement" claim. that only applies to the results of compression (i.e. *storage*), which you explained in the first paragraph. in *memory* (uncompressed of course), a pyramid takes the same space, gaussian or laplacian.

Comment: i meant storage